# Python create n number of class instances

Tags: python, class, oop, object, instance

I have the current code:

```
 class Stock:

    def __init__(self,name,price):

         self.name = name
         self.price = price

 name='MSFT'
 price=100
 obj1= Stock(name,price)
```

However This only works for creating a single instance of the class, what if I have a list with hundreds of names, how do I create the object variable names and initialize them?

Comment: What do you mean? You can create as many instances you want... (within memory limitations)

Comment: you can not dynamicaly create a name for object but you can always have a list and append new instances to it

Comment: @Sarathsp you can dynamically create names for objects, but its messy and inefficient.

Comment: @Gaelephor i mean not necessary here .You ca always do it using exec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you got a names list and a prices list, you can use `zip` and list comprehension:

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C']
prices = [100, 200, 300]
objects = [Stock(name, price) for name, price in zip(names, prices)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're referring to this, you may want to use [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

```
>>> class Stock:
...     def __init__(self, name, price):
...             self.name = name
...             self.price = price
... 
>>> name = 'MSFT'
>>> price = 100
>>> for i in range(10): exec("obj{} = Stock(name, price)".format(i))
... 
>>> obj1
<__main__.Stock object at 0x7ffaf5965e10>
>>> obj1.name
'MSFT'
>>> obj9.price
100
>>> obj0.price
100
>>>
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Mind if I ask why?

Comment: If you are going to do this, which is really a bad practice - these objects should be going into a container, really, like a `list` - but if you *must* then use `globals()`.

Comment: My point is, while you answer is "correct", it is leading the OP astray. Oftentimes, OP asks for X, but what they really need is Y...